# Button functionality disabled by Microsoft on power bi?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have 2 buttons, one of them, unexpectedly stops working with this message:
[image]

The other works as expected:

[image]

I have never seen something similar, ever, in a pbix. What is this?

Comment: What do these buttons do? What actions are on them? It is possible another author wanted to disable this particular button. Maybe these are drill-through buttons and only work when you select a single `DESC`.